# Probability that in two sequences of trials there are the same number of success

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

> There are $n$ children in a class. Teacher gives them all red pencils: each child, independently, may not to take red pencil with probability $p_1$. Then teacher gives them all green pencils: each child may not to take green pencil with probability also $p_1;$ some children can have two pencils. Compute probability that teacher gave the same number of red and green pencil.

By Bernoulli process we know that for fixed $0\leq k \leq n$ probability that teacher gave $k$ red pencils is equal ${n \choose k}(1-p_1)^kp_1^{n-k}.$ Similarly, probability that teacher gave $k$ green pencils is the same. From independence we have that probability that teacher gave $k$ pencils red and $k$ pencils green is ${n\choose k}^2 p_1^{2(n-k)}(1-p_1)^{2k}$ and probability which we want to compute is equal $\sum_{i=0}^n {n\choose k}^2 p_1^{2(n-k)}(1-p_1)^{2k}.$ I have a trouble to compute this sum. Maybe I make mistakes? Or maybe there is easier or better, more didactic, solution? I would be very grateful for your help.

Comment: Would it make it easier to simplify the $p_1$ terms into $p_1^{2n}$ and then take that part out of the sum?

Comment: Where is $(1-p_1)$ in your sum? It definitely should appear.

Comment: It was stupid typo, I corrected this.

Comment: Perhaps the simplest way would be to choose various values for $n$ and compute directly what the answers are for different $n$ in terms of $p_1$. For example, letting $n=3$ we get the answer to be $$20p_1^6 -60p_1^5+78p_1^4 -56p_1^3+24p_1^2-6p_1+1 $$

Comment: Adding on to my previous comment, you can then plot these different answers in the interval [0,1] and notice that the larger the $n$, the smaller the probability that the same number of each pencil was given out. You may also notice that as $p_1$ is more extreme, say closer to $0$ or $1$, there's a greater chance for distributing the same number of each color pencil.

Comment: Is this the original problem text, or have you translated it?

Comment: I don´t see a closed form for the sum due the squaring of the binomial coefficient.

Comment: @Accumulation Yes and no. It's original problem, but I translated it from polish.